# spring mvc controller POST not accepting curl

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a spring boot 1.5 app that I am trying to get working right.  Here is the POST curl I am trying to support:

> curl -i -X POST -d '{ "words": ["read", "dear", "dare"] }' http://localhost:3000/words.json -H "Content-Type: application/json"

And my endpoint is:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/words")
public class WordsController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity addWordsToCorpus(@RequestBody List<String> wordsToAdd) {
...
}
```

however, the values are not making it into the method body with this error:

```
{"timestamp":1487131782829,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@51010449; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@51010449; line: 1, column: 1]","path":"/words.json"}
```

I have Jackson in the path, and I think my curl is submitting valid JSON based upon jsonformatter website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this:

```
curl -i -X POST -d '["read", "dear", "dare"]' http://localhost:3000/words.json -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Or if you want to use `words` to refer `["read", "dear", "dare"]`, you should define a class to be method parameter like this:

```
public class Word {

    private List<String> words;

    setter and getter
}
```

and controller should be

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/words")
public class WordsController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity addWordsToCorpus(@RequestBody Word word) {
...
}
```